# GraphQL DataLoader with multiple one to many relations

Tags: javascript, graphql, typeorm, dataloader, typegraphql

I'm struggling with a good title for this issue, so apologies. For that.

#### What I'm trying to achieve;

I have 3 `Entities` in use for this dataloader

1. `User`
2. `Club`
3. `Player`

- Each `User` can create a `Club`

  - `User` has a `OneToMany` Relationship with `Club`
  - When a `User` creates a `Club` the `User` `id` field is set as the value of the `creatorId` field in `Club`
- The `User` that is the creator of each `Club` can create a `Player` to assign to the `Club`

  - `Club` has a `OneToMany` Relationship with `Player`
  - When a `User` creates a `Player` at a club the `Club` `id` field is set as the value of the `userId` field in `Player`
  - A `User` who is a creator of a `Club` can link a `Player` to a `User`, the `id` field is set as the value of the `userId` field in `Player`

So essentially a single `User` can be both a creator of a `Club` and a `Player` of a `Club`, so can be linked to a `Club` by either being a creator of a player of the club.

#### The issue

I want a `FieldResolver` field called `allClubs` to return all `Club`s in which the `User` is either the creator or the player of a club.

This is what I currently have

```
@FieldResolver(() => [Club])

@Loader<number, Club[]>(
  async (
    userIds,
    {
      context: {
        req: {
          session: { userId },
        },
      },
    }: { context: MyContext },
  ) => {
    // get all clubs where user is either creator or a player
    const clubs = await getConnection()
      .getRepository(Club)
      .createQueryBuilder('c')
      .distinct()
      .leftJoinAndMapMany('c.players', Player, 'p', 'c."id" = p."clubId"')
      .where('c."creatorId" In (:...userIds)', { userIds })
      .orWhere('p."userId" = :userId', { userId })
      .getMany();

    // group all clubs by creatorId
    const clubsById = groupBy(clubs, 'creatorId');

    return userIds.map((id) => clubsById[id] ?? []);
  },
)

allClubs(@Root() root: User): (dataloader: DataLoader<number, Club[]>) => Promise<Club[]> {
  return (dataloader: DataLoader<number, Club[]>) => dataloader.load(root.id);
}
```

So, I need the field to return an array of `Club`

I currently have the `key` of the DataLoader as the `User` `id`

Inside the `Loader` I have a query that returns all of the clubs where the user is either the creator or the player of the club. With the following structure returned

```
Club {
  id: 5,
  name: 'Club Name',
  creatorId: 10,
  players: [ 
    Player {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Player name',
      clubId: 5,
    },
    Player {
      id: 7,
      name: 'Player name 2',
      clubId: 5,
    } 
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure how to group it correctly so that when I loop over all of the provided user ids from the `key` that I can retrieve where the user is a player.

Currently, it's only where the user is the creator

Let's say for the above example the `User` `id` is `7`, they are not the creator of the `Club`, but they are a `Player`, how would I ensure that, that `Club` gets returned in the `Loader` and not just those `Club`s where they are creator?

Any ideas how I can maybe restructure the query in some way to achieve this, or any other methods to achieve the same would be very much appreciated.